# Remover MySQL root após criar outro usuário com todos privilegios

Tags: mysql

Nesse tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-and-mariadb-databases-in-a-linux-vps

Após criar um novo usuário com os privilégios que eu preciso, eles recomendam que eu renomeie o usuário root para assegurar ainda mais o acesso, sendo que um hacker além de descobrir a senha, teria que descobrir o usuário.

Dúvidas:

Como criei um novo usuário e dei todos os privilégios a ele, ainda preciso do root? Não posso remover o root e usar apenas o novo usuário que criei?

Se eu remover o usuário root, preciso remover os 3 que estão cadastrados na tabela User (tabela de usuários abaixo)?

Porque são 3 cadastrados e não apenas 1?

```
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user             | host      | password                                  |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost | *DE06E242B88EFB1FE4B5083587C260BACB2A6158 |
| piucco           | localhost | *D8DECEC305209EEFEC43008E1D420E1AA06B19E0 |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 | *DE06E242B88EFB1FE4B5083587C260BACB2A6158 |
| root             | ::1       | *DE06E242B88EFB1FE4B5083587C260BACB2A6158 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | *ECE81E38F064E50419F3074004A8352B6A683390 |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: "Após criar um novo usuário com os privilégios que eu preciso" que você precisa só na sua aplicação específica, ou que você *poderá precisar em qualquer tempo, em qualquer caso, em qualquer circunstância?...* Se você criou um usuário com todas as permissões possíveis, você criou um clone do *root* (não mais seguro que usar o *root* na sua aplicação, que como você deve saber, é uma péssima ideia); caso contrário, como você fará caso um dia precise de mais permissões? Ter um usuário *root* é importante, mudar seu nome está ok mas removê-lo poderia te trancar de fora do seu próprio SGBD.

Comment: P.S. Essas senhas aí foram anonimizadas? Mesmo estando hasheadas (acho) e *talvez* não tendo aparecido o hash inteiro, agora a internet inteira as conhece, melhor trocá-las todas se esse for um ambiente importante. A propósito, os 3 roots é porque o que conta é a combinação `user@host`, e o MySql vê de forma diferente `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` e `::1` (por que eu não sei, não tenho experiência com isso). Mais detalhes [aqui](http://serverfault.com/q/570289/106111) (em inglês).

Comment: Criei um outro usuário dando os privilégios necessários apenas para a minha atual aplicação (SELECT, UPDATE e DELETE). Nesse caso irei mesmo precisar do root apenas para quando precisar de novos usuários e alterar permissões. Não utilizando o root na minha aplicação, já me torna seguro ou ainda seria melhor renomea-lo e aplicar alguma restrição de uso(via PHP por exemplo)?

Comment: Isso já foge um pouco da minha *expertise*, mas eu diria que não é necessário paranoia demais em relação ao root não - apenas atribua-lhe uma senha *bastante* forte (ex. uma sequência aleatória e longa, que você manterá segura *offline*) que não possa ser descoberta em tempo hábil por atacantes humanos ou automatizados. *Não atrapalha* mudar o nome do root, eu só não escolheria `newAdminUser` como no artigo porque muita gente deve usar esse nome, diminuindo um pouco a "surpresa"... Em vez disso eu faria do nome uma "segunda senha". Quanto a restrições de uso, não tenho conhecimento disso.

Comment: E quando te disseram enter "newpass", não era pra você por "newpass" literalmente, como está no seu DB :P

Comment: Se o DB for esse mesmo, seu "root" só tem permissão da máquina local, como o @mgibsonbr comentou. Não chega a ser uma necessidade você mudar o nome do root. Mas mal não faz, desde que você não esqueça futuramente o nome que pôs. Fica a dica em caso de desespero: Iniciar o MySQL com `--skip-grant-tables` transforma todo acesso em root, assim dá pra consertar um DB "trancado" em que você não tem os dados de _root_.

Comment: Os usuários com o hash que informei foi com os dados do tutorial. Só pra exemplificar. Entendi. Vou esquecer essa paranóia :D

Comment: O usuário responsável pela aplicação não pode ter os mesmos privilégios de um **root**, deve ser menos capaz, e a própria aplicação não deve fazer uso direito do usuário **root**.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo replicar em todas maquinas (`Host`) os usuarios (`Users`), sendo as padrão:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'%';

CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'usuario'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'127.0.0.1';

CREATE USER 'usuario'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'::1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'::1';
```

Verifique em sua aplicação se existe outro tipo de mascara para os `hosts`.
Se realmente deseja remover o root basta executar o script abaixo, deixando ciente que o processo não poderá ser revertido via comando, recomendo fazer um backup da pasta antes de executar o procedimento.

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE  user = 'root';
```

Sendo replicado os usuários de forma devida com todos privilégios (`ALL PRIVILEGES`), a ausência do usuário chamado root não afeta em absolutamente nada, pois é o tipo de usuário que efetua a ação e não seu nome.

Comment: O numero de usuários replicados em cada host dependem se na procedure, function foram usados, o usuario pode criar uma função usando o host "%", outra usando "127.0.0.1", caso faça isso, se não existir o usuário no respectivo host dará erro na função/procedure.

Comment: A resposta é legal como referência, mas pra fazer isso é mais fácil renomear o root pra usuário, e dar um `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` em vez de criar tudo de novo e deletar. E tem uma pequena falha: faltou o `WITH  GRANT OPTION`, senão você nao consegue criar novos usuários,